# How does wifi connection open before I login?

Tags: wireless, login, encryption

When I'm on the lightdm screen, I notice that my WPA wifi connection becomes available.

This is cool, but somethings bothers me:

how does it happen while I did not login yet, so I did not provide my password, so the gnome-keyring is locked and supposedly encrypted?

What is the trick? Is my keyring encrypted and safe?

Comment: Did you select "System Connection" in the network settings? Then no, the credentials aren't stored in your user keyring.

Comment: Yes, I did select "System Connection". You're right. So where is the password stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @gertvdijk stated, the WiFi passwords are not saved in your keyring. It will not be unlocked unless you enter your password, so it is safe :-)

You can however change the behavior of the connections. If you go to `Edit Connections...` in the networking menu and edit a connection, there is an option on the `General` tab called `All users may connect to this network`. If you uncheck it, it will not connect before you log in. As far as I know, in this case the password is not saved in your keyring either.

Comment: It seems non "System connections" are stored in the gnome-keyring. Else they are stored under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/. Unencrypted, but belonging to root. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/22174/where-does-network-manager-store-wpa-keys-when-available-to-all-users-is-ticke

Comment: Ah, good to know. Wasn't sure about that point.